# jQuery-Knob: is it possible to have a range?

Tags: javascript, jquery-knob

I am trying to use jQuery Knob for a thermostat UI. I would like to allow for the ability to control a range (heat - cool).

I've been able to achieve this look by stacking several knobs, however, this essentially disabled the clicking/dragging functionality.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tk9fpjx/2/)

Red cursor: Heat, Blue cursor: Cool, White cursor: current temp.

```
// Obligatory code for Fiddle link    
<input type="text" class="knob1" value="56">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to customize the appearance of jQuery knob, but as per the current behavior of knob we can't add additional handles with it.

Alternatively you can use the jQuery [**roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin, which is very flexible to use so that we can add multiple handles with a single slider.

Check the exact demo for your requirement: [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/utqgufx0/6/)

**Screenshot of the Output:**

[image: thermostat UI like appearance using jquery round slider]

Comment: Are you kidding me? This is absolutely awesome. it never ceases to amaze me how kind some people are! I would mark this as the answer if I could. Thank you, kind stranger!